# Textarea highlight: offset when empty lines left

Tags: javascript, html, regex, angularjs, textarea

I have a multi value textarea reading/writing from/to ng-model(array).

I have a div(highlighter) that acts like a mask containing same values than ng-model but highlighting the values that return false on "NaN(value)".

If I press enter within the textarea a new line is created. This line doesn't become part of the array of values(ng-model) until something is typed. If nothing is typed and a new empty line is created an offset will occur between the highlight mask and the textarea.

[image]

Sugestions???

If this is not done everything works fine:

[image]

View:

```
<script type="text/ng-template" id="form_field_float">
  <div spellcheck="false">
    <div class="highlighter" id="mirror">
      <div ng-repeat=" x in dbo.attributes[attobj.name] track by $index" ng-controller="textVal">
        <div ng-if="!check(x)"><span>{{ x }}</span></div>
        <div ng-if="check(x)">{{ x }}</div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <textarea id="textarea" rows="{{dbo.attributes[attobj.name].length + 2}}" ng-model="dbo.attributes[attobj.name]" ng-list="&#10;" ng-trim="false"></textarea>
  </div>
</script>
```

Controller:

```
  app.controller('textVal', ['$scope',
        function ($scope) {      
             $scope.check = function(valueToCheck){
                if(!isNaN(valueToCheck)){
                  return true;
                } else{ return false;}
             }
        }
   ]);
```

CSS:

```
  .highlighter, #textarea {
      width: 100%; 
  }



  .highlighter {
      position: absolute;
      padding: 1px;
      margin-left: 1px;
      color: white;

  }

  .highlighter span {

      color: red;
      background: red;
      opacity:.4;
  }

  #textarea {
      position: relative;
      background-color: transparent;
  }
```

If I would now add the following custom directive to the textarea I would disable the press of enter twice consecutively BUT if invalid values are highlighted in rows below where I am creating a new row than an offset of one line/row will occur between the highlighter div and the textarea values because I am not creating the same empty line in the highlighter div. Even though both the textarea and the highlighter div are tied to the same ng-model the ng-model doesnt store empty lines as values. The offset disappears as soon as a value is typed in within the new empty line but i wish the highlighter div to adapt when this happens  :

```
  app.directive('noTwolines', function () {

      return {
          restrict: 'A',
          require: '?ngModel',

          link: function (scope, element, attrs, ngModel) {
              if (!ngModel) return;
              ngModel.$parsers.unshift(function (inputValue) {
                  var digits = inputValue;
                  var textarea= document.getElementById("textarea");
                  var val = textarea.value;
                  var caretPos = val.slice(0, textarea.selectionStart).length;
                  console.log(inputValue.length);
                  console.log(val.slice(0, textarea.selectionStart).length);

                  if(caretPos === inputValue.length){
                    console.log('enter from end');
                    digits=  inputValue.replace(/\n{2,}/gm, '\n');
                  }
                  if(caretPos < inputValue.length && inputValue.indexOf('\n\n') != -1){
                    digits=  inputValue.replace(/\n{3,}/gm, '\n');
                  }

                  ngModel.$setViewValue(digits);
                  ngModel.$render();
                  return digits;

              });
          }
      };
  });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what I gather, you do not want the highlight to work on empty spaces. If this is correct, then just add the following line in your code...

```
 app.controller('textVal', ['$scope',
    function ($scope) {      
         $scope.check = function(valueToCheck){
            // new code just below...
            if( !isNaN(valueToCheck) || (valueToCheck.trim() === '')){
            // trim just assures no whitespace.
              return true;
            } else{ return false;}
         }
    }
]);
```

Comment: Thanks I came up with the same solution, forgot to post it. Thank u!